# How to write a hive UDF that can process multiple records

Tags: hadoop, hive, udf

Consider there is a table with columns 'a' and 'b'. There is a situation where I need to have a UDF that packs columns values of 'a' of 10 records in a json array and processes in a bulk instead of one instance of UDF called for each record.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What you'll need is a [UDAF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedAggregateFunction.html), a `UDF` only handles one row at a time.

Comment: This is extremely vague.  An example would be helpful.